# SIRD Url won't resolve

Tags: scala, playframework

I’m currently evaluating the play framework for a new project. I’m looking at something pretty simple but I can’t seem to get it to work. I want to move the simple router for the count example onto the routing DSL. For example

```
->     /count                       controllers.CountRouter
```

and then the following lives in the app/controllers dir

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.routing.Router.Routes
import play.api.routing.SimpleRouter
import play.api.routing.sird._

class CountRouter @Inject()(controller: CountController)
  extends SimpleRouter {

  override def routes: Routes = {
    case GET(p"/") => controller.count
  }
}
```

But it won’t resolve.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced. It's likely because you aren't calling the URI properly.

```
class CountRouter @Inject()(controller: CountController)
  extends SimpleRouter {

  override def routes: Routes = {
    case GET(p"/") => controller.count
  }
}
```

Would yield `localhost:9000/count/` and not `localhost:9000/count`
If you add the following route and visit `localhost:9000/count/yo` it will resolve fine.

```
class CountRouter @Inject()(controller: CountController)
  extends SimpleRouter {

  override def routes: Routes = {
    case GET(p"/") => controller.count
    case GET(p"/yo") => controller.count
  }
}
```